# Phonegap unsupported plugin, no update

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

gap to build an app of my(bulk sms),the config.xml file   throws an error of unsupported plugin when i use phone gap to build it. 
i used the new phone-gap update for some of the plugin which i think works but this

> plugin here

"com.kolwit.pickcontact"   `<gap:plugin name="com.kolwit.pickcontact" version="~1" source="pgb"/>`

i cannot find an update for it.
i went through phone gap plugins but i can't find the plugin.
please help me with its update or an equivalent plugin which is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to resolve the issues by changing the source to npm.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.kolwit.pickcontact" version="~1" source="npm"/>
```